# Do Google Earth and Google Earth Pro need separate tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Currently we have tags for:

- [google-earth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth) with 584 questions and a wiki excerpt of:

> Google's virtual globe application that allows users to view 3D
>   buildings, imagery, terrain, any other information stored in KML
>   files.

- [google-earth-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-pro) with 94 questions and a wiki excerpt of:

> Google Earth Pro is a 3D interactive globe that can be used to aid
>   planning, analysis and decision making

At one time the Pro version cost money for some extra features while the first one was free.  Nowadays [both are free](https://www.google.com/earth/versions/#earth-pro) and there are [other versions for web (Chrome) and mobile](https://www.google.com/earth/versions/).

Do we need both of the tags above and do we need additional tags for the web and mobile versions?

Comment: I think consensus is clear that we want one tag to encompass [tag:google-earth], [tag:google-earth-pro] and [tag:google-earth-desktop] so I'm creating that and making [tag:google-earth] the master.  The master can be easily reset later, if needed.  There does not seem to be clear consensus on any changes needed to other `google-earth-*` tags so I'll leave those changes for another Meta GIS Q&A to sort out later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Id say one tag for google-earth and google-earth-pro is enough because they are very similar and as you have already mentioned google-earth-pro is now free as well, so there shouldn't be many users left using the "normal" version.

But in my opinion there should be an extra tag for the "new" google earth (web/mobile) version as they are different from the desktop program. A separate tag can avoid confusion on which version is meant.

Comment: Hope what I implemented is close enough to what you proposed.  I know it's not identical in all aspects.

Answer (score 3):

I propose simplifying the Google Earth (GE) tags into just one - [google-earth](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth) - and have any/all others as synonyms of that tag (excluding the engine and api tags).

Most of the questions relate to GE or GE-Pro (basically the same product); I don't really see any need to have additional tags for GE mobile or browser which may only attract a handful of questions, if any.

I think it also might be worth looking at the [google-earth api tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-earth-engine-javascript-api+or+google-earth-api+or+google-earth-engine-python-api)

Answer (score 2):

Suggest merging normal and pro into 'google-earth-desktop' and the seperately have 'google-earth-mobile'